# Java Label usage

Tags: java

Somewhere going through java good articles, I found that such code compiles perfectly.

```
public int myMethod(){
    http://www.google.com
    return 1;
}
```

description says that `http:` word will be treated as label and `//www.google.com` as comment

I am not getting how Java Label is useful outside loop?
Under what situation Java Label outside loop should be used?

Comment: It shouldn't be used outside of the loops if avoidable. Not part of the java mindset, anyway, because it introduces complexity.

Like having multiple returns in a function.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is one benefit of using labels in Java:

```
block:
{
    // some code

    if(condition) break block;

    // rest of code that won't be executed if condition is true
}
```

Another usage with nested-loops:

```
outterLoop: for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    while(condition)
    {
        // some code

        if(someConditon) break outterLoop; // break the for-loop
        if(anotherConditon) break; // break the while-loop

        // another code
    }

    // more code
}
```

or:

```
outterLoop: for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    while(condition)
    {
        // some code

        if(someConditon) continue outterLoop; // go to the next iteration of the for-loop
        if(anotherConditon) continue; // go to the next iteration of the while-loop

        // another code
    }

    // more code
}
```

Comment: your second sample with `continue outterLoop` is pretty senseless as you can use a simple `break` there. It would make sense in a deeper loop. Or am I totally wrong?

Comment: @WarrenFaith You're right. Updated the answer.

Comment: Damn, never mind, missed something :D

Comment: The previous example would not be senseless at all if there were any code after the while loop and still inside the for loop.

Comment: @Math You are correct. Updated the answer ;)

Answer (score -1):

Just because it compiles does not mean it is useful.....

Labels are often overlooked in Java (who uses labelled `break`, and `continue` ...? ). But, just because the label is not used does not mean it is illegal.